# convert a Date&Time in PST time zone to UTC

Tags: javascript, utc

I have tried goggling the results to convert data &time in pst to utc time zone.I couldn't find any.Could anyone pls help me how to achieve this.Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned a link in the comments:
[Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

That answer deals with timezones explicitly. I favor another approach: if you call `new Date().getTime()` you will always get the milliseconds in UTC. Then, no matter what timezone you're in when you reconstruct your date, you can use code like the following:

```
var offsetMillis = -date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

function convertToDate(){
  var utcMillis = document.getElementById('leftMillis').value;
  var x = new Number(utcMillis);
  var date = new Date(x);
  document.getElementById('leftDate').value=date.toDateString()+' '+date.toLocaleTimeString();
  x -= offsetMillis;
  date = new Date(x);
  document.getElementById('leftUTCDate').value=date.toDateString()+' '+date.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

What you're doing is to subtract the offset to UTC from the current UTC millis. I like this option because it deals with the string formatting nicely.

[Paste some UTC milliseconds](http://currentmillis.com/) in the left column of that site to see that code in action.

Another option (and probably the more standard one?) is to simply construct the date: `new Date(millis)` and then use the UTC methods from the date: `getUTCHours()`, etc.